# Setting the maxlength of Textarea

Tags: textarea, maxlength, html-input

I have created a textarea where I've set the maxlength to 350 characters and row="5". It works perfectly if I enter characters normally.

Then when I copy-pasted the data with 2-3 Enters, it stopped taking characters less than 350.

I just want to understand how it works and what all use-cases that I need to cover to implement it correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the line break in a text is encoded with invisible characters. In Windows operating systems, it's a combination of two characters : CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed). In unix-like operating systems, there is only one character LF (line feed).

CR and LF characters are counted in the maxlength, and that's the reason why your textarea seems to take less than 350 characters.

You can do some tests with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxtvLens/1/).

```
<body>
  1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>
  <textarea rows="5" maxlength="10"></textarea> 
</body>
```

If you copy-paste the full columns of digits into the textarea, only 5 of them will be pasted in an unix-like operating system, and even less in a windows operating system.